# How to fix "Edited in both" Conflict on Microsoft's git?

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio-2017, branch

I have a project and recently one partner joined to the adventure. The thing is, he has created some files on his own branch while me, on the `master` branch, created some others and edited several others. Now while creating a **Pull request** there are two files with conflict:

> *someProj.csproj*    Edited in both
>   *Web.config* Edited in both
>   **Next steps:** Manually resolve these conflicts and push new changes to the source branch.

How can I fix that?
All I get from Google are Git's command lines to resolve this issue but it is over MS's [visualstudio.com](https://visualstudio.com); I already tried to run the commands on my Visual Studio (2017) but it prompts *"git" command is not valid*.

Other thing I tried to do is manually change these files and now my VS gives me an error:

> ```
> 1>CSC : error CS2001: Source file 'Blahblah.cs' could not be found.
> ```

I don't know what to do since there are several new files on both branches.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure you've solved this by now, but I hit this question when researching the same error message so here is how I resolved it.

Your colleague needs to Merge into his local branch. Merge from origin/ (so I guess origin/master in your scenario).
When this merge happens VS2017 will highlight the conflicts and ask your colleague to resolve manually. Once they have done this, the merge can be committed up to master (your code).

As you probably have realised, working directly on master is a bad idea - you should have branched as well. But to resolve this your colleague needs to get the code from master, merge it locally, and push the changes.